# PLS-00049 error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to add auditing to my table in Oracle db but I keep getting PLS-00049 error. 
Here is my script :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER gfmdev.audit_feature_performance
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON gfmdev.feature_performance
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    osuser  VARCHAR2(8);
BEGIN
    --
    -- get who is making the DML change from the session
    --
    osuser := session_info.osuser;
    --
    IF (NOT (dbms_snapshot.i_am_a_refresh)
    AND dbms_reputil.replication_is_on) THEN
            IF NOT dbms_reputil.from_remote THEN
                IF INSERTING THEN
                    :new.created_by := osuser;
                    :new.creation_date := sysdate;
                    :new.last_updated_by := osuser;
                    :new.last_updated_date := sysdate;
                END IF;
                --
                IF UPDATING THEN
                    :new.last_updated_by := osuser;
                    :new.last_updated_date := sysdate;
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
            -- raise error if we cannot set auditing fields
            raise_application_error(-20505, 'audit_feature_performance Failed. Rolling Back.' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

The error thrown is :

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY'
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DATE'
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY'
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY'
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DATE'
```

I am not able to figure out why is this happening. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the definition of the table `feature_performance` Btw: you know that the value of `osuser` is provided by the client application? There is nothing to prevent the client setting `osuser` to e.g.`foobar`

Comment: MKT_ID    NOT NULL    NUMBER(18)
DEVICE_TYPE   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(38)
GV   NUMBER(18)

Comment: Don't post code in comments. ***Edit*** your question and add the complete definition of the table. But if those _are_ all your columns, then where do you expect `LAST_UPDATED_BY` to come from? You need to have those columns defined on the table.

Comment: You don't seem to have added the `last_updated_by` and `last_updated_date` columns to your table. But you have added `created_by` and `created_date` if you aren't also getting errors for those; so can you add the actual current table definition to the question, as what you put in comments doesn't seem to be complete?

Answer (score 0):

try:

created_by := osuser;
                    :new.creation_date := sysdate;
                    :new.last_updated_by := osuser;
                    :new.last_updated_date

```
alter table gfmdev.feature_performance add (
created_by  varchar2(100),
creation_date date,
LAST_UPDATED_BY varchar2(100),
LAST_UPDATED_DATE date
)
/
```

then execute create trigger command, or recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER gfmdev.audit_feature_performance
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON gfmdev.feature_performance
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
```

Comment: Those are the defaults, so won't make any diference. The columns being referenced don't exist.